# Как получить скрытое api

Tags: javascript, api

Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить скрытое api с помощью консоли разработчика в google chrome

Comment: А почему вы решили, что его вообще можно получить? И при чём тут Javascript и Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В браузере нажми `ctrl`+`shift`+`i`. Перейди на вкладку Network. Поставь галочки `preserve log` и `disable cache`. Изучай запросы и ответы.